# python html EmailMessage strange characters

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, email

I am generating an email based on a template file.
When loading the HTML, the format is ok, as soon as I load it into the msg object some weird characters are added.

```
    try: 
        with open(f'{SCRIPT_ASSET_PATH}email_template_{args.lang}.txt') as f:
            html_data=f.read().replace("templateCustomer",args.customer).replace("templateCode",str(demo_code)).replace("templateFullName",USER_FULLNAME).replace("templateBusinessTitle",USER_BUSINESS_TITLE).replace("templateImage",'<img src="cid:{image_cid}"></img>'.format(image_cid=image_cid[1:-1]))
    except FileNotFoundError: 
        print_fail(f"ERROR loading email template, WILL NOT prepare email. Check if email_template_{args.lang}.txt is in assets folder")
        return False
    print(html_data) # here it is fine
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = "Demo access"
    msg['From'] = settings["userEmail"]
    msg['To'] = "fillin@customerdomain.com"
    msg.make_alternative() 
    msg.add_alternative(html_data, subtype='html') # something happens here
```

In the `msg._payload` there are now some random characters (normal letters, an equal sign etc) added 
        like *"3D"*:  href=3D"www.mylink.com"

Why could that be? It seems not to be related to HTML specific characters I need to specially encode. In example an "list=d" is added to a simple string "products" containing no special characters:

> You can now try out the use case with the products listed below.

becomes

> You can now try out the  use case with the products list=ed below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really tricky to find out the right way of handling this. There are also many answers around but as soon as something was fixed, something else broke (image embedding did not work, hyperlinks had an issue etc.)

I managed to solve it the following way now:

```
cid=str(uuid.uuid4())
    try: 
        with open(f'{SCRIPT_ASSET_PATH}email_template_{args.lang}.txt') as f:
            html_data=f.read().replace("templateImage",'<img src="cid:{image_cid}"></img>'.format(image_cid=cid))
            html_data = html_data.encode("ascii", "xmlcharrefreplace") # this repairs any broken special characters in the mail

    except FileNotFoundError: 
        print_fail(f"ERROR loading email template, WILL NOT prepare email. Check if email_template_{args.lang}.txt is in scriptfolder")
        return False

    msg = MIMEMultipart('related') # nearly every other post pointed me to "alternative" but alternative broke the image embedding
    msg['Subject'] = "Demo access"
    msg['From'] = settings["userEmail"]
    msg['To'] = "fillin@customerdomain.com"
    text = "Automatic demo email did not work as expected, please contact us."


    outfile_name = f"{assets_path}email_template.eml"
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html_data, 'html', 'utf-8')
    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)
    with open(f'{assets_path}merged.jpg', 'rb') as img:
        mime = MIMEBase('image', 'jpg', filename='merged.jpg')
        mime.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='merged.jpg')
        mime.add_header('X-Attachment-Id', cid)
        mime.add_header('Content-ID', f'<{cid}>')
        mime.set_payload(img.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(mime)
        msg.attach(mime)

    with open(outfile_name, 'w') as outfile:
        gen = Generator(outfile)
        gen.flatten(msg=msg)
```